# How to migrate pandas read_sql from psycopg2 to sqlalchemy with a tuple as one of the query params

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

With pandas=1.4.0, it emits a Warning about not using `psycopg2` directly within `read_sql`, but to use `sqlalchemy`.  While attempting to do such a migration, I can not resolve how to pass a `tuple` as one of the query parameters.  For example, this presently works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

read_sql(
    "SELECT * from news where id in %s",
    psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydatabase"),
    params=[(1, 2, 3),],
)
```

attempting to migrate this to `sqlalchemy` like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
read_sql(
    "SELECT * from news where id in %s",
    "postgresql://localhost/mydatabase",
    params=[(1, 2, 3),],
)
```

results in

```
...snipped...
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

So how do I pass a `tuple` as a `params` argument within pandas `read_sql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your query with a SQLAlchemy [text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) object, [use named parameters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#specifying-bound-parameter-behaviors) and pass the parameter values as a dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import text
read_sql(
    text("SELECT * from news where id in :ids"),
    "postgresql://localhost/mydatabase",
    params={'id': (1, 2, 3),},
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I could not edit it to correct the dict key to be `ids` :)  You have made my day!